# Zoom in Activities is it possible?

Tags: civievent, activities, admin, zoom

I have explored a bit about the possibility of integrating [Zoom](https://zoom.us/) as a virtual meeting tool for **CiviCRM Activities**. It would be great to have a Zoom **URL generator** in CiviCRM's "Meeting" Activity type.

I was looking at the [CiviZoom](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civizoom) integration but this **only works for** **Events** and not Activities.

Is it possible to have a Zoom integration in CiviCRM activities to generate URLS like in Events?

Comment: not currently as far as I know

Comment: You might want to reach out directly to the authors of CiviZoom to discuss sponsoring that feature